# How can I open two Minitab application and execute command via .NET?

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to open two separate `Minitab` application from my `.Net` application and want to execute command seperately for two charts that will be displayed in coressponding `Minitab` application.

I tried with following but it returning same handle which refer to same application.

```
 MtbApp1 = new Mtb.Application();
 MtbApp2 = new Mtb.Application();
```

Comment: Hi,how to use the Mtb,I mean ,how to add the namespace,using Mtb = What?I have add the com library "Minitab 18.0 Addin Interface",is there any doc or guide?

Answer (score 0):

Minitab automation is not what you might expect. By design, I think the assumption is that any code you write will be to augment an existing user session of Minitab.  So if the Minitab UI is open at the time you make the first call, the handle would be to that session and you could do stuff with the same workbook/sheets.

The second call would open a new process.  Similarly, if there is no UI open before your code executes and you added a third new Mtb.Application() call, a second process would appear with a new handle.  The minitab help file on automation has some information about the options, but doesn't seem to cover this little detail.